# Flink pipeline with firing results on event

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have stream of objects with address and list of organizations:

```java
@Data
class TaggedObject {
    String address;
    List<String> organizations;
}
```

Is there a way to do the following using apache flink:

1. Merge organization lists for objects with same address
2. Send all results to Sink when some event occurs. E.g. when user sends control message to a kafka topic or another DataSource
3. Keep all objects for future accumulations

I tried using global window and custom trigger:

```java
public class MyTrigger extends Trigger<TaggedObject, GlobalWindow> {
    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(TaggedObject element, long timestamp, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (element instanceof Control) return TriggerResult.FIRE;
        else return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }
```

But it seems to give only Control element as a result. Other elements were ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a generic control signal that triggers output for ALL addresses, then you'll need to use a [broadcast stream](https://flink.apache.org/2019/06/26/broadcast-state.html). You combine your stream of addresses with your control stream and then perform the appropriate logic (merging organizations for an address, or triggering output) inside of your custom implementation of a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`.

Comment: Dear kkrugler. Thanks for your answer. Your approach worked for me. Here is code that works! https://github.com/evgenycheryomushkin/stackoverflow-flink

Comment: Good to hear, and thanks for posting the code!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should just key the stream by address and then use a KeyedProcessFunction (with a List- or MapState) to store the different organizations. Then as soon as an event comes in, you can just output the entries of the State.

Kind Regards
Dominik

Comment: Dear Dominic, you idea is not working for me. Please look at https://github.com/evgenycheryomushkin/stackoverflow-flink